# Mtp connection for nexus 10 12.04

Tags: mtp

Very new to ubuntu cant find anything about a nexus 10 tried many commands for similar mtp but still no luck

Answer (score 1):

I use 13.04 and found out that my MTP worked perfectly fine and I have a Sandisk Sansa Clip Zip+ which is one of the most temperamental and problematic brands of MP3 players on any and every OS that uses the MTP file system.

Comment: GParted has nothing to do with MTP. The reason why MTP is working for you is because of the GVFS-MTP that was newly added to 13.04.